# Javascript Date() will not update live when setHours() is set

Tags: javascript

If "now.setHours()" is set, the date() no longer updates live in console, why?

```
 setInterval(function() {

             // Get servers date and time from users timezone
          var now = new Date();
              now.setHours(<?php echo date('H, i, s'); ?>); //will not work with sethours set.

              console.log(now);


        }, 1000);
```

Comment: The problem may be from the input to the `setHours()`. For example it works fine with `now.setHours(11)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It indeed was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above:

The problem may be from the input to the setHours(). For example it works fine with now.setHours(11). – Addis